# Survey banner "hide" setting is not persisted across refreshes

Tags: bug

The survey banner should stay hidden after page reload. Seems it's not persisted properly.

[image]

Comment: I think it should stay hidden after I take the survey as well, but it does not.

Comment: Already escalated to the staff for review (see [[meta-tag:status-review]] tag on the linked duplicate). Agreed that this is an incredibly annoying bug. Perhaps you can express your opinions on the survey?

Comment: I'm surprised you reported the banner reappearing as a bug and not the whole page being replaced by an angry face emoji

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering how he managed to get that screen capture of the seekrit mod tools, @Nick.

Comment: @CodyGray The problem is the linked duplicate is over a month old and no official word. This should really be an easy fix.